# How to save a var to the local computer?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I have difficulties with saving a var from javascript to a local file, so I want to write it into an existing file. I can do it with creating and downloading a file but I need it without the browser asking if and where to store the file/var. Is there any way of doing it? Need it because I want to automatically save the var so that my main program (runs locally) can get it. I scrolled through many sites but I couldn't find anything that fit my needs so I unfortunately don't have any code.

Thanks Akira

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the main programm is running you can have the webpage talk to it via http, websockets or webrtc to localhost.

Comment: I will try one of your versions. Thanks.

Comment: For all others who see this question, here are some use fill pages: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_server , https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/WebSockets

Answer (score 1):

no there is no way of doing that as it is a security risk and the user needs to confirm the location of the file. The only thing you could do is set a default filename so the user would be required to overwrite the existing file.

Answer (score 0):

It may be preferable to use a database instead ? Your main program will retrieve the variables in it.

Comment: If I use a DB where to put it that my addon and my program have access?